# How do I change the Identity authorization path in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I created an `Account` folder with an `AccountController`, `Login` and `Register` views, and links to those views on my layout page. That all work fine, and the path looks like this:

```
localhost/Account/Login
```

My problem started when I added `[Authorize]` to a controller. When I click on a link handled by that controller, instead of routing to my `Login` view, it routes to:

```
localhost/Identity/Account/Login
```

Is there somewhere in `Startup.cs` or some other file where I can change that default path so that it routes to my `Login` page instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Startup.cs` class

In this method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

You need to add

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the login path by configuring the cookie options:

in your `Startup.cs`

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/access-denied";
                options.LoginPath = "/login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
            });
```